# Configuration changes that will not import?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have some configuration that will not import. If I run `drush config-import --preview` I see the changes to be imported; I hit 'y' to import. When I run the same command, the changes are still there?

My guess is that when I run this command the config files should say to the database: 'hey, be like me'. Then when I run it again, Drupal should ask 'are the config files and database the same?' - they should be if they were synced - and Drupal should say 'cool, nothing to do, they match'. Right?

Am I missing something - if not, what can I do? Thanks.

```
$ drush config-import --preview
 Collection  Config                                            Operation                
             core.entity_view_display.node.page.search_result  update 
             core.entity_view_display.node.page.search_index   update 
             core.entity_view_display.node.book.teaser         update
Import the listed configuration changes? (y/n): y
The configuration was imported successfully.                                                                                                                                                     [success]
$ drush config-import --preview
 Collection  Config                                            Operation                
             core.entity_view_display.node.page.search_result  update 
             core.entity_view_display.node.page.search_index   update 
             core.entity_view_display.node.book.teaser         update
Import the listed configuration changes? (y/n):
```

Comment: I've also experienced this.

Comment: I'm moving the config from my dev site to stage site. All I can think to do is delete the stage database and replace it with the dev database. Then the flies will be out of sync - so I'd have to copy those over too.

Comment: cache is rebuilt ?? run --preview diff to see the actual changes - maybe they're different ..

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this is a problem with how drush generates the temp files to compare against. It looks like drush is generating files with any comments removed as well as not adding qoutes around yaml strings that needs to be escaped.

```
+  # Set the node type to location
   type:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: location
+  # set the location type to park
   field_location_type:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value:
       tid: 1
+  # Create the mappings from soap to drupal fields.
   title: abbreviatedName
   field_location_active_facilityid: ID
-  field_location_address/address_line1: address1
-  field_location_address/locality: city
-  field_location_address/administrative_area: state
-  field_location_address/postal_code: zipCode
-  field_location_address/country_code: country
-  field_location_parking_direction/format:
+  "field_location_address/address_line1": address1
+#  "field_location_address/address_line2": address2
+  "field_location_address/locality": city
+  "field_location_address/administrative_area": state
+  "field_location_address/postal_code": zipCode
+  "field_location_address/country_code": country
+#  "field_location_address/langcode":
+#    plugin: default_value
+#    default_value: en
+  "field_location_parking_direction/format":
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: basic_html
-  field_location_parking_direction/value: parkingCapacity
+  "field_location_parking_direction/value": parkingCapacity
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this, too. Sometimes the configuration seems to be modified during or after the import thus there will be a difference between what is on disk and what is in the database.

It may be a module acting on the import event by adding its own default settings to the configs.

It could help to re-export the configuration and compare the result with the original files in order to understand what is going on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/137489)

Comment: "Am I missing something - if not, what can I do?"  That's the question I think I answered based on the available information.

Comment: You have a point. In fact perhaps the question should be closed as it fosters discussion, which is against the rules of this forum.